How to send mails from multiple domains using Google SMTP
I recently migrated two of my website from shared hosting to Ubuntu VPS. My services:

VPS configured for multi website hosting
2 domains on GoDaddy (managed by GoDaddy DNS)
2 Google Workspaces with emails attached

On shared hosting those websites have got created emails, but MX record in DNS was pointed to Google SMTP in order to use G Workspace.
For now everything's the same, but after migration to VPS I installed sendmail and tried to send the test email but it's not working. PHP mail() function returns code 500.
How can i set sendmail to use multiple mail addresses with Google Workspace SMTP?
